# FTP_ASCII in Python

Tags: python, ftp

I am trying to build a small FTPClient as my pet project and have come this far.

```
from ftplib import FTP

class FTPClient():

    connection_id = None
    login_ok = False
    message_array = []

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def log_message(self, message, clear=True):
        if clear:
            self.message_array = message

    def get_message(self):
        return self.message_array

    def connect(self, server, ftp_user, ftp_password, is_passive = False):
        self.connection_id = FTP.connect(server)
        login_result = FTP.login(self.connection_id, ftp_user, ftp_password)
        FTP.set_pasv(self.connection_id, is_passive)

        if not self.connection_id or not login_result:
            self.log_message("FTP Connection has Failed")
            self.log_message("Attempted to connect to {0} for {1}".format(server, ftp_user))
            return False
        else:
            self.log_message("Connected to {0} for {1}".format(server, ftp_user))
            self.login_ok = True
            return True

    def make_dir(self, directory):
        if FTP.mkd(self.connection_id, directory):
            self.log_message("Directory {0} created successfully".format(directory))
            return True
        else:
            self.log_message("Failed creating directory")
            return False


    def upload_file(self, file_from, file_to):
        ascii_array = ['txt','csv']
        extension = file_from.split(".")[-1]
        if extension in ascii_array:
            mode = # FTP_ASCII
        else:
            mode = # FTP_BINARY
```

I am currently testing if extension appears in the list of file extensions that should be uploaded as type ascii. If it appears in the list, we set the variable mode to ASCII; otherwise, we assume it’s of binary type, and assign mode the value BINARY.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`storelines`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storlines) for ASCII trasnfer mode, [`storebinary`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) for binary transfer mode.

```
def upload_file(self, file_from, file_to):
    if file_from.lower().endswith(('.txt', '.csv')):
        with open(file_from, 'r') as f:
            self.connection_id.storelines('STOR {}'.format(file_to), f)
    else:
        with open(file_from, 'rb') as f:
            self.connection_id.storebinary('STOR {}'.format(file_to), f)
```

Side note: You can use [`str.endswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.endswith) to check file extension:

```
>>> 'a.csv'.endswith(('.txt', '.csv'))
True
>>> 'a.txt'.endswith(('.txt', '.csv'))
True
>>> 'a.bin'.endswith(('.txt', '.csv'))
False
```

---

BTW, why do you use unbound methods (`FTP.login(self.connection_id, ...)`)
instead of bound methods (`self.connection_id.login(...)`) ?

```
>>> s = "STRING"
>>> str.lower(s) # unbound method
'string'
>>> s.lower()    # bound method
'string'
```

Comment: Any advantage of using bound methods ?

Comment: @ajkumar25, Do you really want to repeat that `FTP`? What if the class name is `SomethingLikeThisVeryLooooooooongClass`?